# How to set attribute with brackets in name in checkbox in Ionic 2 / Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I would like to use custom defined color **for checkbox** from app.variables.scss based on boolean value in some variable. It's easy for button:

`<button [class.button-customcolor]="variable" [class.button-defaultcolor]="!variable" (click)=whatever()>click</button>`

if I wouldn't use variable, it would look like:

`<ion-checkbox customcolor checked="false">`

But checkbox has SCSS different name *ion-checkbox[girl] .checkbox-checked { ...* , which I can't use because of brackets. This throws errors in console:

```
<ion-checkbox [class.ion-checkbox[customcolor]]="true" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
```

*Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[class.ion-checkbox[customcolor]]' is not a valid attribute name.*

This might be solved as workaround by making custom class with simple name, but this must have some other easy solution, which I wasn't able to find.

**So, how can I use those brackets in HTML/Ionic tag?**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [NgClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html)?

Implementation would me something like:

```
<ion-checkbox [ngClass]="{class.ion-checkbox[customcolor]: variable}" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: thanks, beware, it seem to me that you are missing some quotes in [ngClass]="{'class.ion-checkbox[customcolor]': variable}" :). In this particular example, this doesn't work as I provided you with bad CSS/SCSS, but you made me being on the right track!